# How to auto format code file *.ctp in PDT Helios?

Tags: php, eclipse, cakephp, eclipse-pdt

I am using Eclipse for PHP (PDT) Helios, how to auto format `CakePHP Template file`?
 
For example: when I follow [this tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html)  , when I edit file `index.ctp` like this:

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/index.ctp -->

<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($post); ?>
</table>
```

I don't undestand how Eclipse autoformat above snippet code. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: THIS IS not CODING related Question, You should ASK `how to format in Eclipse??`

Comment: Dear friend, @jQueryAngryBird, I don't think so. If my question not good, let's revise this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this like my follow screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Aptana Studio (is based on Eclipse) try this:

```
Window / Preferences / General / Editors / File Associations
```

If You haven't .ctp file, You must add it, after add to this extension `Assiociated files` to PHP